# API call to local alfresco copy

Tags: api, alfresco, alfresco-share

I have a local copy of Alfresco on my system . Also, i have my own application(php) that will make API request to Alfresco to upload files.

Is it possible to make API request to my local copy of Alfresco? If yes, can you please guide me on this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes its possible, an index of all the CMIS webscripts can be found at `http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/index/family/CMIS` if you have an default alfresco installation.

To get going I would have a look at the Apache Chemistry for php:
http://chemistry.apache.org/php/phpclient.html

Comment: I was able to do this with webscripts available with the installation.